# How can i see Magento2 Rest API errors as a 3rd party developer?

Tags: api, magento

We are working with Magento 2 REST APIs to pull back all orders. Periodically, it throws with a 500 error and reference to a webapi #. As a 3rd party provider, I don't have access to the /logs directories to see the error.

Is there a way for us to see language around the error with only the token for a store (how we are authenticating).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: here is the error we're getting :  Response Body: {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-6090347a6ada0"}

Comment: and the api call  https://xxxx.com/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-12-15&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2021-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&searchCriteria[currentPage]=2&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100